# version hdf5 for h5py

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

Good afternoon!
I install h5py for the python 3.6

```
pip install h5py
```

It uses the version hdf5 1.10.2 [print(h5py.version.info)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmLWL.png)

How to install h5py with the required version HDF5 = 1.10.0 ?

Comment: always the latest version is installed. Why do you want 1.10.0?

Comment: For compatibility with my application. in it I use hdf5 = 1.10.0.
When using the python which I am at the root of the program it uses hdf5.dll from my program, not from Lib \ site-packages \ h5py \ hdf5.dll

Comment: We need more context. Why do you have a hdf5.dll "at the root of the program"? Is it only a Python program? Why do you work within the directory with compiled object files? A clean build process (i.e. using cmake) could solve your issues by separating the build and executable files.

Comment: @beginning_user Did you try pip install h5py==1.10.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can install using your local version of HDF5 with: `pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py --user`